# How to use Lombok's toBuilder on @SuperBuilder

Tags: java, builder, lombok

Currently I have these three classes:

```
@Value
@NonFinal
@SuperBuilder
public class Parent {
    // Some fields
}

@Value
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class ChildA extends Parent {
    // Some fields
}

@Value
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class ChildB extends Parent {
    // Some fields
}
```

I want to use it in a mapper as follows to avoid duplicating any code:

```
private ChildA buildChildA(Entity entity) {
    Parent parent = ((ChildB) buildParent(entity, ChildA.builder().build()))
        .toBuilder()
        // Populate Child A fields from entity
        .build();
}

private ChildB buildChildB(Entity entity) {
    Parent parent = ((ChildA) buildParent(entity, ChildA.builder().build()))
        .toBuilder()
        // Populate Child B fields from entity
        .build();
}

private Parent buildParent(Partner entity, Parent parent) {
    return parent.toBuilder()
        // Populate Parent fields here
        .build();
}
```

However when I try to compile I get:

```
ChildA.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype 
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true) 
^ 
ChildB.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype 
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true) 
^ 
2 errors
```

How do you use toBuilder with @SuperBuilder? I'm using lombok v1.18.4.

Comment: Both `ChildA` and `ChildB` don't seem to extend Parent, is this deliberate?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to use `@SuperBuilder` with `toBuilder`, all classes in the hierarchy must have `toBuilder=true`. The reason is that the `toBuilder()` method only copies the field values from its respective class, but delegates the copying of the field values from the supertypes to the supertypes' `toBuilder()` methods.

So just add `toBuilder=true` to your `Parent` class, too.