# Lombok @SuperBuilder - convert an object from one child class to another, preserving the parents' fields

Tags: java, reflection, lombok, builder

I need to convert an instance of one class to a "sibling" class (both inheriting from the same parent) without explicitly setting common/parents' fields. The goal is to make this "mapping" resilient to changes to the parent class as fields are added or removed. Here are the basics of the classes I'm working with:

Parent:

```
@NonFinal
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public abstract class Parent {
    String parentProp;
}
```

ChildA:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class ChildA extends Parent {
    String childAProp;
}
```

ChildB:

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class ChildB extends Parent {
    String childBProp;
}
```

Given `childA` instance of `ClassA`, I want to convert/map it to `ClassB`, ideally doing something like this:

```
var childB = ChildB.builder()
  .parentBuilder((ParentBuilder)childA.toBuilder())
  .setChildBProp("childB")
  .build();
```

I haven't found a way to accomplish this using lombok, but wondering if I just missed something obvious. If this isn't possible with lombok, is reflection the best option here? I have access to the classes' source, so I can modify them, but again, I want to avoid setting parents' properties explicitly. Thanks!

Edit: it looks like this is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197544/how-to-use-lomboks-tobuilder-on-superbuilder), with a key different of their `Parent` class not being abstract.

Comment: There is a similar question with an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66783284/can-i-use-the-lombok-builder-passing-the-parent-class-as-parameter/66817135#66817135).

Answer (score 1):

You can add such a `parentBuilder` method into the parent's builder class, which will then be inherited by all the child builders. The parent builder has a private static method called `$fillValuesFromInstanceIntoBuilder`, which you can use to copy all the properties in an instance of the subclass to `this`.

Because `$fillValuesFromInstanceIntoBuilder` takes an instance of the built object, `parentBuilder` can just take an instance of `Parent`, instead of a builder type.

```
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public abstract class Parent {
    String parentProp;
    // the name and generic parameters of this class must match the 
    // abstract builder class that lombok would have generated
    public static abstract class ParentBuilder<C extends Parent, B extends ParentBuilder<C, B>> {
        public B parentBuilder(Parent p) {
            $fillValuesFromInstanceIntoBuilder(p, this);
            return self();
        }
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
ChildA a = ChildA.builder()
        .parentProp("Parent Prop")
        .childAProp("Child A Prop")
        .build();
ChildB b = ChildB.builder()
        .parentBuilder(a)
        .childBProp("Child B Prop")
        .build();
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

I think (I haven't tried it) this generalises to multiple levels of inheritance. You just need to do something like the above for every class that have subclasses.